# Remove Data from Column Mysql keeping part of string

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a column in mysql db table which has email address and regular usernames.

I need to run a query which can remove the "@domain.com" from each row but keep the rest if it's an email.

Not sure how to go about it.

Comment: Is @domain.com a fixed string or are you talking about generic e-mail addresses?

Comment: generic e-mails, all different.

Answer (score 0):

how about using substring ?

```
 SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX('www.mysql.com', '.', 2);
    returns: 'www.mysql'
```